# software updater not updating ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, software-updater

I think some settings have been changed and I cannot update my Ubuntu 13.04 using the software updater.....please help me as I am new to this OS
Here are the screenshot of my problem..

[image]
[image]

If you need more info about the system please ask...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Once its done, run Update Manager to install the updates again. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to click "Partial Upgrade". That will install some packages, when it's done you should can update completely.